# Config file options for a multi-key -> value map

Tags: java, yaml, config

I'd like to make a static config file for a Java Application, where I have multiple inputs mapping to a output value (something like a composite HashMap key to a value). What would be the best config to represent something like this

Abstract example of such a csv config would be:

```
Apple, Orange, Banana -> Value1
Orange, Apple, Banana -> Value2
```

Can this be represented better in a YAML? If so, what would be the best way to represent this in a yaml. Are there better alternatives than a csv/yaml/json?

Comment: I believe this question already has an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54914535/how-can-i-set-same-value-for-multiple-keys-in-java-properties)

Comment: If you're up for it, read up on [domain-specific languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) (DSLs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YAML allows you to do

```
[Apple, Orange, Banana]: Value1
```

Which maps the *sequence* `[Apple, Orange, Banana]` (not each of the contained items) to the given value. You can also write the sequence in block style:

```
? - Apple
  - Orange
  - Banana
: Value1
```

The `?` starts an explicit key, containing the list. The `:` starts the value. The two code examples are equivalent.